# How to ignore parent dependencies in mvn versions:display-dependency-updates?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`

This will output a long list if you use a `<parent>` dependency like `spring-boot-starter-parent`

`pom.xml`:


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.6.7

Result:

```
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependency Management have newer versions:
[INFO]   antlr:antlr ........................................ 2.7.7 -> 20030911
[INFO]   com.atomikos:transactions-jdbc ........................ 4.0.6 -> 5.0.9
[INFO]   com.atomikos:transactions-jms ......................... 4.0.6 -> 5.0.9
[INFO]   com.atomikos:transactions-jta ......................... 4.0.6 -> 5.0.9
[INFO]   com.couchbase.client:java-client ...................... 3.2.6 -> 3.3.0
[INFO]   com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core ................... 4.13.0 -> 4.14.1
[INFO]   com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core-shaded ............ 4.13.0 -> 4.14.1
[INFO]   com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-processor ....... 4.13.0 -> 4.14.1
[INFO]   com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-runtime ......... 4.13.0 -> 4.14.1
[INFO]   com.datastax.oss:java-driver-metrics-micrometer ..... 4.13.0 -> 4.14.1
[INFO]   com.datastax.oss:java-driver-metrics-microprofile ... 4.13.0 -> 4.14.1
....
```

Question: how can I tell maven to check only on self-defined dependency versions, instead of the one inherited? Something like `-Dparent=ignore`?

Comment: Please check: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html#processDependencyManagement

Answer (score 0):

`mvn versions:display-property-updates` solves it. But requires to include all self-added dependency versions into `<properties>` section.